# Global Action not showing new event on contact in salesforce Lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, global-actions

I want to create new event in lightning experience, but my contact detail page in noty showing up the new Event option in Global Action. How can i get it ? Do i need to change any setting?

Comment: Have you looked at your Contact Detail page to see what Global Actions are enabled for it? Under lightning, Check the [Lightning Modules](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/modules) in Trailhead for Getting Started with Lightning Setup as I believe some of that setup may be unique in Lightning.